# Asp.net WebApi2 default routing not finding different named apis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have two WebApi2 actions, each work fine alone:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MigrateUser([FromBody] MigrateUserModel userInfo)
```

and

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ChangeEmail([FromBody] ChangeEmailModel model)
```

When they are both present, I get a 404 error for both. What must I do to make both POST .../ChangeEmail and .../MigrateUser be found? Is there a way to do this without explicit Attribute Based routing (which would be?).

The following HttpGet work fine, no Route() required...

```
       [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public async Task<TcMarketUserFullV1> GetIdmCtoUsrFromEmail(string email)
```

and

```
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public async Task<TcMarketUserFullV1> GetIdmCtoUsrFromGuid(string ctoguid)
```

Comment: use Route() attribute to defferentiate both.

Comment: You suggest AttributeRouting is the only way? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Yes, AttributeRouting is the way, But I am not saying this is **Only** the way to handle, May be there is another way.

Comment: Can you please share url you use to call both action for HttpGet ? I am just curious to know.

Comment: Updated above. Both are addressed with simplest form of url and query parame as "base-url/action-name?param=xyz". Works fine, that is why I was surprised to see that post/body requires additions.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming `HttpGet` action is differentiate by params name but post method has model as a parameter, so `HttpPost` require extra work to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Route` attribute to diff. each action.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost,Route("migrate")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MigrateUser([FromBody] MigrateUserModel userInfo)
```

and

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost,Route("change")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ChangeEmail([FromBody] ChangeEmailModel model)
```

Comment: Thanks. So Route("migrageuser") , Route("changeemail").